# Why is C++'s void type only half-heartedly a unit type?

Tags: c++, types

C++'s `void` type is not uninhabited. The problem is that while it has precisely one inhabitant, very much like the `Unit` type (a.k.a. `()`) in ML-like languages, that inhabitant cannot be named or passed around as an ordinary value. For example, the following code fails to compile:

```
void foo(void a) { return; }
void bar() { foo(foo()); }
```

whereas equivalent (say) Rust code would compile just fine:

```
fn foo(a : ()) { return; }
fn bar() { foo(foo(())); }
```

In effect, `void` is like a `unit` type, but only half-heartedly so. Why is this the case?

Does the C++ standard explicitly state that one cannot create values of type `void`? If yes, what is the rationale behind this decision? If not, why does the code above not compile?

If it is some backwards-compatibility related reason, please give a code example.

To be clear, I'm not looking for work-arounds to the problem (e.g. using an empty struct/class). I want to know the historical reason(s) behind the status quo.

EDIT: I've changed the syntax in the code examples slightly to make it clear that I'm not trying to hijack existing syntax like `void foo(void)` (consequently, some comments may be out of date). The primary motivation behind the question is "why is the type system not like X" and *not* "why does this bit of syntax not behave as I'd like it to". Please keep this point in mind if you're writing an answer talking about breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: There is a [regular void](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html) proposal, which you might find interesting. :)

Comment: The historical reason is that `void` and almost all of its properties comes directly from C.  Asking why C didn't take a feature from ML is backwards; C is older than ML.  So I'm not certain what you are asking; why C++ didn't change void from C's void?

Comment: @AdamNevraumont I'm not asking "why C didn't take a feature from ML.". I'm asking "why hasn't C++ taken this feature from ML, given that it already has a half-hearted version of it.". E.g. they've added `std::monostate` instead of fleshing out `void`, which is in essence a work-around...

Comment: @Rakete1111 thank you for pointing that out; I didn't know about that! I've got a new proposal to follow :)

Comment: Wouldn't `std::monostate` be the ML analog?  (And not a workaround.)  Or would you want C++ to change the semantics of `void`, and break backwards compatibility, and significantly thwart C interoperability.  (C interoperability already has a list of caveats, pitfalls, and concerns.  Changing the semantics of void would be dire.)

Comment: `std::monostate` is like a user-defined unit type (`type u = U`) in ML, not _the_ unit type. One of the reasons for this is that the type of a statement is `void`, not `std::monostate`. W.r.t. "break backwards compatibility" -- could you please give a code example (as asked in the question), preferably in an answer (instead of a comment), which compiles now but wouldn't compile if `void`'s inhabitant was named? The regular void proposal claims that it will not break ABI compatibility in practice.

Comment: @theindigamer: Your suggestion breaks `void f(void); f();` which is valid code today.  Note that the regular void proposal leaves the code in your question illegal, in order to avoid breaking my example.

Comment: @theindigamer: Also, it's not correct to say that "the type of a statement is `void`".  Expressions have type, statements which are expressions may not have `void` type, and statements which are not expressions have no type at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the code in my question is an example using existing syntax. If `void` were actually allowed as a value (in the ideal scenario), I would expect to be able to write `void foo(void a) { return; }`, not the implementation above. So no, I'm not suggesting breaking the current syntax. W.r.t. the type of a statement, I would love to read a citation. Also, my compilers professor would disagree with you. [See section 2](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4120/2018sp/lectures/10typesystems/lec10-sp16.pdf?1516816840)

Comment: @theindigamer: Just because an academic gives you a description (in lambda calculus) of a language (Xi) where statements have type, does not mean it is true in C++.  I see no claims about C++ in that pdf.

Comment: Please, I'd like to not get into an argument. It makes a point about Java, where `void` is very much like C++. As I wrote earlier, could you please provide a citation? I tried looking for proper descriptions of the C++ type system but wasn't able to find any that discussed `void` in detail.

Comment: @theindigamer: If by a "proper description" you mean a formal type calculus, none exists.  I think there is actually a formal proof that no such thing exists. C++ is not a regular language, and its typing rules have many many exceptions.  That's why theoretical CS courses tend to use Java-like languages, not C++, because the grammar and type systems in Java are much more suitable for formalization (Besides which, "Xi" isn't exactly Java.  Java statements also don't have type, unless they are expressions.  You can't do `(if (false) {}).getType()`.  In Xi, you could.)

Comment: You could probably keep a dozen philosophers busy for a week to get them to define the value of *nothingness*.  Engineers take the shortcut to their somewhat inevitable conclusion, it has no value.  Other than its usage to express the concept of *nothing* or *undefined* in a language.  Do note that the function declaration is C, in C++ that kind of nothingness gets expressed with nothing.

Comment: See https://wg21.link/p0146r1 for the proposal to make void work like this.

Comment: @theindigamer "type of an *expression* ([basic.types]) resulting from analysis of the program without considering execution semantics" [\[defns.static.type\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.static.type) – emphasis mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Does the C++ standard explicitly state that one cannot create values of type void?"

Yes. It states that `void` is an *incomplete type* and cannot be completed. You can't create objects or values with an incomplete type.

This is an old rule; as the comments note it's inherited from C. There are minor extensions in C++ to simplify the writing of generic code, e.g. `void f(); void g() { return f(); }` is legal.

There seems to be little gain in changing the status quo. C++ is not an academic language. Purity is not a goal. Writing useful program is, but how does such a proposal help with that? To quote Raymond Chen, every proposal starts at -100 and has to justify its addition; you don't justify the lack of features.

Comment: I'd like to respectfully disagree. Not all features have the same cost in terms of change and complexity (the -100 bit) and should not be held to the same standard. Two examples I can come up with off the top of my head - (1) I was trying to write an eDSL lately and having a `void` overload would've been the most ergonomic and (2) Adding a proper unit type paves way to add a proper uninhabited type which has its own [set of advantages](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/08/13/never-patterns-exhaustive-matching-and-uninhabited-types-oh-my/).

Comment: Also, w.r.t. "C++ is not an academic language. Purity is not a goal.". Well, look where that has got us in terms of language complexity? Even parsing it is so challenging. Not getting rid of small inconsistencies (`void` is the only type which is both incomplete and cannot be completed) makes understanding the type system more challenging. Is ease of understanding not a goal too?

Comment: @theindigamer I'm with you in that C++ has evolved to be too complex for its own good. Nevertheless, the special handling of `void` does seem to be adequate: When you declare something as `void`, you literally are declaring that it does not exist. At least that's the case for function arguments and return values. What you propose is de-facto passing/returning NULL instead. `void*` pointers are even more special as they can convert to/from any other pointer type implicitly in C. C++ changed this for better type safety, but that is the main reason why much good C code is not legal C++ code.

Comment: @theindigamer: Let me be more explicit. `void` is very intentionally incomplete. This gives the authors of generic library code a very useful else-case. If it didn't exist, there would be people asking for such a type. You can never satisfy both demands. Similarly, some languages have a universal `Object` base class, which is unique because it itself has no base class. Again there's no objective measure to judge whether this is a good design..

Comment: @MSalters could you elaborate on "gives the authors of generic library code a very useful else-case" in your answer? I know Rust implements [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) by setting the value type to `()` in HashMaps (this is a zero-cost abstraction) but I do not know of similar examples in C++, though I'm happy to learn about them. If you want an uninhabited type, Rust has `Never` and Haskell has `Void`.

Comment: @cmaster, I'm not proposing passing/return NULL. The memory representation of `()` is an implementation detail and "passing it around" can be trivially elided by the compiler. My question is about the _type system_ and does not make any suggestions related to the _operational semantics_ of the program.

Comment: @theindigamer: Example where `void` is useful: in template recursion, it's common to use a template specialization for `void` to end the recursion.

Comment: @typesanitizer: Actually C does have an uninhabitable type `_Noreturn void` (used to be spelled `volatile void`).

Answer (score 3):

That is really an historical question. Old (pre-C) language used to differentiate *functions* which returned values, from *subroutines* which did not (ooh, the good old taste of Fortran IV and Basic...). AFAIK, early C only allowed functions, simply functions were by default returning `int` and it was legal to have no return statement (mean return an unspecified value) and legal to ignore any return value - so that the programmer can write coherent code... In those early days, C was used more or less as a powerful macro assembler, and anything was allowed provided the compiler can translate it into machine instructions (no strict aliasing rule for example...). As the memory unit was `char`, no need for `void *` pointer, `char *` was enough.

Then people felt the need to make clear that a buffer was expected to contain anything and not a character string, and that some *functions* will never return a value. And `void` came to feel the gap.

The drawback, is that when you declare a `void` function, you declare what was called a *subroutine*, that is something that can never be used as a value, in particular never be used as a function parameter. So `void` is not only a special type that can never be instantiated, it really declare that the result cannot be a member of an expression.

And because of language inheritance, and because the C standard library is still a subset of the C++ standard one, C++ still processes `void` the way ANSI C did.

Other languages can use different conventions. In Python for example a function will always return something, simply it returns the special `None` value if no return statement is encountered. And rust seem to have still another convention.

Comment: Just to make sure that I'm understanding you correctly: are you (indirectly?) suggesting that providing an inhabitant for `void` in the type system means that you must break backwards compatibility with ANSI C?

Comment: @theindigamer No. I was just giving the history to explain why thing are what they are.